# Inconsistent syntax coloring in a post

Tags: support, code-formatting

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131507/update-a-field-of-an-existing-instance), I'm getting the syntax coloring properly on the first section but not on the second one. I suspect that it's got to do with it being within an enumerated list. What can I do about it?

I've tried to explicitly set the language as follows but that didn't help.

```
<!-- language: lang-csharp -->
```

The tags are set correctly, of course.

Comment: I'm not using <pre>. Someone else had added these. However, now that I got the highlight working, I see that the enumeration died...

Comment: Moooaaaar spaces!

Comment: Got it! @Mat - Put it as an answer. And specify that it's eight of such and not just *moooaaaar*, hihi. Explain why as well. And then ya'll be checked green!   :)

Comment: @Konrad Hihi? `The Stitchbird or Hihi (Notiomystis cincta) is a rare honeyeater-like bird endemic to the North Island and adjacent offshore islands of New Zealand. It became extirpated everywhere except Little Barrier Island but has been reintroduced to three other island sanctuaries and two locations on the North Island mainland. Its evolutionary relationships have long puzzled ornithologists, but it is now classed as the only member of its own family, the Notiomystidae.`

Comment: @bjb568 I meant, of course, "hihi" as a more chuckling derivative of "haha" (soundification of a laughter, I must add, because I trust that you can find some obscure alternative to that as well). Good one, at any rate.   :)

Comment: @Konrad Oh. `HAHA: Human anti-human antibody, a measure of antibody response`